# Using UML to describe voting and commenting process

Tags: uml

What is the best way to describe a commenting and voting process as we have it here on SO in UML? I need a clear way to describe that one user asks a question, multiple users submit answers and each user can upvote / downvote answers and the question as he likes.

I tried to model that using an activity diagram that starts on top, has to branches, one branch that goes to a node that says "comment", the other one goes in a "voting" action. Each action then has a flow to itself (representing that the user can upvote / downvote and comment as often as he wants) and then both join in a final node.

I do not think that this is in any way comprehensible so I want to ask: what is the correct way to describe this using UML?

Comment: Are you interested in a component view or run-time behavioral view?

Comment: Im interested in a run time behavioral view.

Comment: You still have to start with a component view. Run-time view will show you instances of those components, and by itself, it's not the best view to see properties of relationships between components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to describe the rules (i.e. relationships) then a class diagram is probably more appropriate than an activity diagram.  Here's a pretty crude but nevertheless representative example:
[image: class diagram: question-answer-vote]

Activity diagrams are appropriate for describing chained activities (processes).  In this case however, the behaviour is pretty simple; a User can submit Posts (Question or Answer) and also vote on Posts.

The diagram captures the following rules (reading directly from the relationships):

```
Each User may submit many Posts
A User need not submit any Posts
Each Post must be submitted by exactly one User
Each User may vote on many Posts
A User need not vote on any Posts
Each Post may be voted on by many Users
A Post need not be voted on by any Users
Each Vote has a type which is either up or down
A Post is either a Question or an Answer
A Question may have many Answers
A Question need not have any Answers
Each Answer must be a response to exactly one Question
```

Note the model is missing some important rules (e.g. can't up/down vote your own posts).  Also missing Comments (another subtype of Post) and other salient attributes (e.g. User name, Post text, etc.).  Hopefully representative enough for purpose though.

hth.

PS: I took liberties with syntax for `Vote.type`.  It should really be defined as an enumeration, but for these purposes the way it's shown is sufficient.  Apologies to any lurking UML police :-)